# how to pass NSMutableArray of images on UIActivityViewController initWithActivityItems

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *shareImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i < unknown_count; i++)
{
    //add images to shareImages
}

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithActivityItems:@[
shareImages
                                                        ] applicationActivities:nil];
```

The above code doesn't work. How to pass unknown number of images?

Comment: instead of initWithActivityItems:@[shareImages] try to write initWithActivityItems:shareImages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kabarga answered above "instead of initWithActivityItems:@[shareImages] try to write initWithActivityItems:shareImages".
It worked.

```
NSMutableArray *shareImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i < unknown_count; i++)
{
    //add images to shareImages
}
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                            initWithActivityItems:shareImages
                                                            ] applicationActivities:nil];
```